# Math.log is not working - why?

Tags: java

//  The method below is not working correctly and I am not sure why. The log results are not correct.  0.5 is returning log value -0.6931471805599453 but my calculator shows it should be returning -.3.

```
public static void printCommonLogTable()
{
    double x = 0;
    while (x <= 10) 
      {
       System.out.println (x+ "  " + Math.log(x));
       x = x + .5;
      } 
}
```

Comment: Some calculators call the natural log `ln`.

Answer (score 6):

The [`Math.log` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) uses base `e`, the natural log, not the common log, base `10`.  The natural log of `0.5` is `-0.6931471805599453`.

> Returns the natural logarithm (base e) of a double value.

Use the [`Math.log10` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29) for the common log (base 10).

> Returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value.

Comment: Thank you.  We did not realize the natural log vs log10.  That answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Java's [Math.log](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) function uses **base e** and the answer you are getting from java appears to be the correct answer.

I think your test calculator is using a base other than e.

Java uses base e because you you can can easily calculate **log base x of y** using log base e with this formula

```
double log_base_x_of_y = Math.log(y)/Math.log(x);
```

This is called the *[change of base formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).*

Answer (score 0):

Because log, like the log method in any standard math library, uses base e. The answer you get is correct in that sense. You need a different computation to compute a log in the base you are thinking of.